# Dreamweaver compatibly with Mojave

Tags: mojave, adobe

I know some apps in CS6 work and others don’t in Mojave. Has anyone tested Dreamweaver CS6 specifically?

Comment: According to https://roaringapps.com/app/adobe-dreamweaver-cs6, it does.

Answer (score 1):

Dreamweaver CS6 does not work if you upgrade to Mojave.

I just did the OS install  and now dreamweaver CS6 won't work.

Comment: I seem to be successfully running Dreamweaver CS6 on Mojave - haven't hit a snag so far, at least. I did not upgrade to Mojave, but installed CS6 on a Mac with Mojave already installed; maybe that makes a difference. You could perhaps try re-installing DW. (I also downloaded the legacy Java engine from Apple.)

Answer (score 1):

I also had problems with some old software, including Adobe Photoshop CS5. It wouldn't even open for me. So I asked here about it and got an answer that works. I think you should try it too...

https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/344672/312788

It basically says to enable the apps in your Accessibility settings.

From Monomeeth's answer...

> 1 Go to Apple > System Preferences…
>
> 2 Click on Security & Privacy
>
> 3 Select the Privacy tab at top right
>
> 4 In the lefthand pane select the Accessibility option
>
> 5 At bottom left of the window make sure the padlock is unlocked (if not, select it and enter your password)
>
> 6 In the list of apps on the right-hand side, make sure Photoshop and any of the other apps you’re having problems with are ticked
>
> 7 OPTIONAL: If any apps you’re having problems with are not listed, click on the + button under the list and navigate to the apps to
> select and add them to your list. Once done, then repeat Step 6
>
> 8 Make sure you lock the padlock again that you unlocked at Step 5
>
> 9 Quit and restart any apps you’ve just allowed to control your Mac (i.e. if they were already open)

Good luck! :-)

Comment: Thanks for linking the two issues! Would you edit the post above to explain what "try it too" means in case the linked question or answer gets edited?

Comment: @bmike That's a good idea. I have quoted the steps from the other answer.

Comment: Is that way my answer had a negative score?

Comment: I have no idea why anyone would down vote this, but people are free to do so. +1 to both answers here is my vote. you were clear that you didn’t try this but had some ideas what to do and also cited a reference